# Pushing notification from smartphone to smartwatch

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm developing an application where the user can create his own tasks and then he gets a notification when the time comes. So my question is how to push these notifications to his smartwatch? do I really need to code something or just write some wearable features and then synchronize them by using Bluetooth?

Comment: I believe [the introduction to android wear](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/index.html) answers your question.

Comment: Yeah it answers my question, thanks a lot bro.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to code anything Android Wear specific. Just use the `NotificationCompat.Builder` to build your notification on your phone and it will show up on your Android Wear device.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have another question, what about the notification sound? Will it be the same for both or the default for smartwatch?

Comment: The smart watch doesn't have a sound device. It can only vibrate. You need Bluetooth smart headphones to listen to sounds from your smartwatch. For notification sounds... I don't know. Never used them.